# Как передать аргумент в onclick функцию при нажатии кнопки Python

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Как передать аргумент в onclick функцию при нажатии кнопки на Python. GUI пишу на Tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
def foo(event): # Функция для кнопки 'event' обязательный параметр
    print('Hello World!')
    print(entry.get())
root = Tk() # Создаём окно
btn = Button(root, text='Print') # Создаём кнопку
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
btn.pack() # Отображаем кнопку
btn.bind('<Button-1>', foo) # Передаем функцию при нажатии кнопки
root.mainloop() # Отображаем окно
```

Comment: Мне нужно не просто использовать функции при нажатии, а передать  аргумент в функцию, например, что б при нажатии кнопки  визивалась функция foo(arg), где arg- мое число или строка

Comment: Вам нужно создать поле и ввести в него данные, после чего вывести их. Поправил ответ

Comment: В общем, у меня есть клас где есть списо кнопок и форма одна для введения стрингов, есть функции delete(btn), что принимает в аргументи им'я кнопки, на которую нажали. То есть при нажатии кнопки btn3 будет функция delete(bnt3)

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma вы можете `lambda: delete(bnt3)` явно передать или из контекста вычислить, если больше подходит в вашем случае. Обновите ваш вопрос и приведите полный, но минимальный пример кода, который ваш случай показывает (всё подряд не нужно включать)—если можете суть проблемы с одной кнопкой объяснить, то используйте только одну итд.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать лямбда-выражения, как в ответе @Lo_okiMan, а можно воспользоваться `partial` из библиотеки [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Минимальный пример:

```
import tkinter
from functools import partial

def test_reaction(test_text, event = None):
    print(test_text)

root = tkinter.Tk()
command_btn = tkinter.Button(root, text='Command button', 
                             command=partial(test_reaction, "Command test"))
lambda_btn = tkinter.Button(root, text='Lambda',
                            command=lambda x = 'Lambda test': test_reaction(x))
bind_btn = tkinter.Button(root, text='Bind button')
bind_btn.bind("<Button-1>", partial(test_reaction, "Bind test"))

command_btn.pack()
lambda_btn.pack()
bind_btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Кнопка `command_btn` получает ссылку на функцию через аргумент `command` при создании и выводит текст `Command test`.
Кнопка `lambda_btn` вызывает функцию через лямбда-выражение, передавая ей аргумент в качестве значения по умолчанию.
Кнопка `bind_btn` получает ссылку на функцию через метод `bind`. Следует учитывать, что `bind` также передаёт `event`, поэтому в функцию `test_reaction` добавлен второй аргумент `event` со значением по умолчанию `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

def delete_widget(event):
    event.widget.destroy()

root = Tk()
buts = []
for i in range(3):
    buts.append(Button(root, text = "Delete me!"))
    buts[i].pack()
    buts[i].bind("<Button-1>", delete_widget)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать так:

```
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: func(arg1, arg2, ...) )
```